# Auto-refreshing powerpivot for excel 2010 using VBA / Macros

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

I need to build a button in either VBA or Macro to auto-refresh an excel 2010 workbook using powerpivot data. Anyone know how to go about doing it? Nothing I've tried has seemed to work, and a handful of examples online seem to be less than promising.

Comment: if you are trying to refresh the powerpivot tables you're outta luck. the data model is not exposed to vba pre-xl2013

Comment: @JosieP There is a somewhat unsupported but still viable way to do this.  The VBA code is here: <https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26587283/ppRefresh.bas> and the blog post is here: <http://blog.gobansaor.com/2011/09/01/automating-powerpivot-refresh-operation-from-vba-the-code/>